# Fastest way to drive a vector of library packages given the vector of packages' names

Tags: r, string, list, parallel-processing, lapply

I am currently trying to see if there is a fast way to apply `library()` into a vector of string elements so that the final vector would result in a list of library of each package. For example, if I have a vector `c("base", "dplyr", "parallel", "RPostgresSQL", "DBI", "rlang")`, and I want to obtain a vector `c(library("base"), library("dplyr"), library("parallel"), library("RPostgresSQL"), library("DBI"), library("rlang")).` My goal is to put this vector of library into `clusterEvalQ()` so that each cluster node can have all the packages to execute the function `clusterMap().`

**My attempt.**

```
lib.list <- unlist(lapply(c("base", "dplyr", "parallel", "RPostgresSQL", "DBI", "rlang")), function(x) paste0('library(',as.character(x), )')) --- only gives me the vector of each string-type library (e.g. "library(base)".)

noquote(lib.list) --- Get rid of the annoying double-quote characters around "library(base)".
```

I have two questions though:

1. It seems to me that each time we execute the `clusterMap()`, we need to execute the `makeCluster()` to refresh each cluster node, if we update the variable `lib.list` in `clusterEvalQ(cl, lib.list)`? I tried executing only the `clusterMap()` but always ended up getting the same result, which does not make sense.
2. Is there a faster way, in terms of execution time, to achieve the original goal?

Comment: Could you broadcast a function that loads libraries from a vector of library names (e. g. `sapply(c("lib1", "lib2"), function(libname) require(libname, character.only = TRUE)`) using `clusterCall`? (Just a guess, no own experience with pkg {parallel})

Comment: I think that works as well, as I tried it andgot the same result as `clusterEvalQ()`. Excellent call :) many thanks for your help.

Comment: Apparently, that only works with Mac, but not Windows 10. Do you happen to know a similar solution for Windows 10? It kept resulting in all the "FALSE" value for each node.